# jQuery logic not working properly

Tags: jquery

Found a really nice code for Accordion nav and am trying implement on our website, but due to certain restrictions I cannot change the HTML codes or new version on jQuery. The example is based on div/class names but we are using ul > li listing. I am not really getting the child parent relationship. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

The code is set up on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/kn3t6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, fixed the jsfiddle to work with your html:

http://jsfiddle.net/kn3t6/6/

Changed this code:

```
 //Main code that should work  
 $(this).parent().slideDown(500).siblings((this).parent).slideUp("slow");
```

To this code:

```
// hide other lists
$(this).parent().siblings().find("ul").slideUp("slow");

// show the current list
$(this).parent().find("ul").slideDown(500);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot man, really appreciate it. Now I can go home and enjoy the evening. cheers...